# Hibernate: using criteria with collections (HashSet)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have the following classes:

```
  public class Folder{
      private Set<Documents> documents;
      private Set<Clip> clips;
  }

  public class Clip{
      private Owner owner;
  }
```

I need to find list of *nice* **documents** in *yellow* **folders** that have **owners** of **clips** in those **folders**, whose *names* are like search string. Something like this (not working):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Document.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("isNice", 1));
criteria.createCriteria("folder").add(Restrictions.eq("isYellow", 1));
criteria.createCriteria("clips");
criteria.createCriteria("owner").add(Restrictions.like("name", search));

List documents = criteria.list();
```

How do i create criteria for HashSet?
Or

- maybe i should use hql query
- Maybe I could edit just `List documents`, removing bad entries?
- Is it even possible with criteria?
- If not what's the another way?

edit. I've found this snippet of code:

```
    List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .createCriteria("kittens", "kt")
        .add( Restrictions.eq("name", "F%") )
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
    .list();
Iterator iter = cats.iterator();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Map map = (Map) iter.next();
    Cat cat = (Cat) map.get(Criteria.ROOT_ALIAS);
    Cat kitten = (Cat) map.get("kt");
}
```

but i cant understand what exactly it does. Whats resultTransformer?

Please, any advice or tip would help so much! Thanks!

Comment: So you want to create a list of nice documents in yellow folders, .... **OR** you want to list all of them and remove **bad** entries? What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I would like to do first, but if its not possible, second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Document.class, "document");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("document.nice", true));
criteria.createAlias("document.folder", "folder");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("folder.yellow", true));
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(clipOwnerWithNameInFolder(name, "folder"));

private DetachedCriteria clipOwnerWithName(String searchedName, String aliasOfFolder) {
    DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Clip.class, "clip");
    c.createAlias("clip.owner", "owner");
    c.createAlias("clip.folder", "clipFolder");
    c.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("clipFolder.id", aliasOfFolder + ".id");
    c.add(Restrictions.like("owner.name", searchedName);
    c.setProjection(Projections.id());
}
```

This needs the Clip/Folder association to be bidirectional (i.e. you need to have a `folder` field in `Clip`). If it's not the case, the detached criteria could be created like this:

```
private DetachedCriteria clipOwnerWithName(String searchedName, String aliasOfFolder) {
    DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Folder.class, "clipFolder");
    c.createAlias("clipFolder.clips", "clip");
    c.createAlias("clip.owner", "owner");
    c.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("clipFolder.id", aliasOfFolder + ".id");
    c.add(Restrictions.like("owner.name", searchedName);
    c.setProjection(Projections.property("clip.id"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! i have problem in 'c.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("clipFolder.id", aliasOfFolder + ".id"); c.add(Restrictions.like("owner.name", searchedName);
'  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: no such column: owner1_.name

Comment: You must have a problem in the mapping of the name property.